# Regular user chown (only change group)

Tags: linux, permissions

While I have seen this question asked multiple times and in a variety of ways, I still haven't found a satisfactory answer.

Due to security issues, I understand that chown can only be run by a superuser.

Can a regular user change just the *group* of a folder or file of which he is the owner?

I have the following issue: While administrating a server, a student (who I would prefer not to add to the sudoers) configures folders and adds content for a web server. If a folder is created in his home folder, how could he change the *group*, not the owner? If he could add the *www* group to his folder, then he would be free to configure nginx and other parameters.

Comment: The command I think you're looking for is `chgrp`

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [su]

Comment: Thank you very much! I had no idea the command even existed. If you add it as an answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Check out `chgrp` command.  It can be used by the file owner to change the group ownership.

Comment: this change the owner too, not only the group

Comment: No, this command only changes the group. chmod will change the owner and can be used to change both the owner and group. chgrp does what it's name implies.

Comment: The syntax is `chgrp GROUPNAME DIR` not the other way around.

Comment: Note you can also use `chown` and not specify a user... `chown :GROUP FILE`. :)